# Unable to recognize OLE stream

Tags: java, jxl

I want to read `xml` file and I use `jxl`. But I get error  `jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream`.

When I search the internet , Everbody say that You should save as Excel 97-2003 Workbook.But My excel file is Excel 97-2003 .How can I solve this ?

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import jxl.Cell; 
import jxl.CellType; 
import jxl.Sheet; 
import jxl.Workbook; 
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException; 

public class deneme { 

  private String inputFile; 

  public void setInputFile(String inputFile) { 
    this.inputFile = inputFile; 
  } 

  public void read() throws IOException  { 
    File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile); 
    Workbook w; 
    try { 
      w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook); 
      // Get the first sheet 
      Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0); 
      // Loop over first 10 column and lines 

      for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) { 
          Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i); 
          CellType type = cell.getType(); 
          if (type == CellType.LABEL) { 
            System.out.println("I got a label " 
                + cell.getContents()); 
          } 

          if (type == CellType.NUMBER) { 
            System.out.println("I got a number " 
                + cell.getContents()); 
          } 

        } 
      } 
    } catch (BiffException e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
      deneme test = new deneme(); 
      test.setInputFile("c:/data.xls"); 
      test.read(); 
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just go and save again by clicking on Save As and choose Excel 97-2003 WorkBook. 
it work for me....

Answer (score 0):

Just renaming it to .xls file does not work.

You will have to manually go to Save as -> Excel 97-2003 Workbook and save it.